# Qt4 and MySQL5 - Binding QByteArray "1:1" as binary data

Tags: sql, mysql, qt, encoding, binary

I have some issues with character encoding of a binary value using Qt4 and MySQL5.

Let's say we want to bind a value containing the four bytes `\xDE \xAD \xBE \xEF`. I check the bound value using the MySQL function `HEX()` using this code:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QSqlRecord>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    if(!db.open("test", "test"))
        exit(1);

    QSqlQuery q("SELECT HEX(?)");
    q.addBindValue(QVariant(QByteArray::fromHex("DEADBEEF")));
    if(!q.exec())
        exit(1);
    if(!q.next())
        exit(1);

    qDebug() << q.record().value(0).toString();

    return a.exec();
}
```

The output of this code is `"DEADEFBFBDEFBFBD"` which is obviously the HEX code of `\xDE \xAD \xBE \xEF` interpreted as a latin1-encoded string and then encoded as a UTF8 string.

If I do not bind the value using addBindValue() but placing it directly into the query using `UNHEX('DEADBEEF')` results in the expected behaviour (which isn't surprising...).

Where does the UTF8 encoding step take place?

(Finally, I want to store a binary value "1:1" into a BLOB field.)

**OS:**  Ubuntu 10.10 (32 bit)
**Qt Version:**  4.7.0 (Ubuntu package)
**MySQL Version:**  5.1.49-1ubuntu8.1

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ok, I think it has something to do with the setup of my MySQL server itself. How can I check / test / set the default connection encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After weeks of trial and error, the only solution I found is to transfer the binary data in hexadecimal code and `UNHEX()` it in the query.

This *is* a solution, so I allow myself to accept my own answer, but it isn't a nice solution and I have no explanation to the behavior of the code above.

So if you have any advice, I am looking forward for any further answer. (I will then accept your answer.) Thanks!